# Multiple Curves With Different Domains in a Single Plot ( with ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library("ggplot2")
eq = function(x){x^-1}
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-6,6)), aes(x = x, y=eq(x)))+
    geom_line(data=as.data.frame(curve(from=-6, to=-.01, eq)))+
    geom_line(data=as.data.frame(curve(from=.01, to=6, eq)))
```

I am trying to produce a single plot, and this code gives me the plot I want, but with two additional plots, one with each geom_line. I don't understand why those additional two plots are being created.

Comment: it is plotting 2 plots because the function `curve` draws plots, and you called this function twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @shayaa noted in the comments, `curve` itself generates plots, which is why you are getting the extra plots.  To avoid this, you can just create a dataframe before you plot, and subset it in `geom_line`:

```
library("ggplot2")
eq = function(x){x^-1}
df <- data.frame(x =seq(-6, 6, 0.01), y = eq(seq(-6, 6, 0.01)))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, x<=-.01), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(data=subset(df, x>=.01), aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Comment: or `transform(data.frame(x=seq(-6,6,0.01)),y=eq(x))`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to my comment above, you don't need two separate calls to `geom_line` to produce this plot. You can use `stat_function` if you redefine your function as follows.

```
eq <- function(x) ifelse(x==0, NA,x^-1)
```

Then you can plot it as follows

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(-6,6,.01))
ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun = eq)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! That is clever. I think I need to draw it in two pieces because I wanted to add arrows at the ends of both lines (4 total).