# Plot asymptotic discontinuity in ggplot2 using a single call to stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this [recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928293/multiple-curves-with-different-domains-in-a-single-plot-with-ggplot2) someone asked how to plot the inverse function using `ggplot2`. Yes, I know that you can plot it trivially using separate calls to `geom_line`, similarly to the answer to that question.

I would like to produce a ggplot which looks like that plot (base R version show below), except using the `stat_function` statistic in `ggplot2`. Is this possible? I'd prefer not to hack the underlying function.

```
eq = function(x){x^-1}
xseq <- seq(-1,1,.01)
plot(xseq, eq(xseq), type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab =" x inverse")
```

[image]

When I plot it using the following ggplot code, I get a undesirable continuous `geom_path` plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=xseq)
ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun = eq)
```

[image]

#### Things I have tried

1. remove the difficulty of plotting `+/- inf` as follows

   ```
   df <- data.frame(x= c(seq(-1,-.01,.01), seq(.01,1, .01)))
   ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun=eq)
   ```
2. Add an `NA` to the mix

   ```
   df <- data.frame(x= c(seq(-1,-.01,.01), NA, seq(.01,1, .01)))
   ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun=eq)
   ```

   2b. Yes, I know ggplot removes `NA`, but not here? Anyone know why not?
3. Add a grouping variable to group them discontinuously

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   df <- df %>% mutate(group = ifelse(x <0 , 1, 2))
   ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x, group = group), fun = eq, geom = "line")
   ```

   3b. Yes, I know, I tried to change the `geom` in that last call.

#### What works

```
eq <- function(x) ifelse(x==0, NA,x^-1)
ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun = eq)
```

This provides the desired result, but it redefines the function, which I don't want to do.

Comment: This may or may not help, but you could wrap the `eq` function instead of modifying `eq`.  A hack like `ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x), fun = function(x) { y<-eq(x); ifelse(is.infinite(y), NA, y) })` works (the wrapper function could be defined outside the call to `stat_function`.

Comment: That's something. Even more hacky than mine. I guess I just think it is lacking in functionality to the 'stat_function' transform that there isn't any option for handling of `inf` and `NA`, or that said functionality isn't apparent.

Comment: It may be worth directing this to the ggplot folks. I suspect this will be a feature request.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ggplot2/eZoQzGjcj-s/fzOFJuNATx0J

Comment: I'll take a look at this @baptiste thanks!